# How to enable chart.cursor vertical and horizontal line in amcharts 4

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts4

I am plotting amcharts 4 , and i need to enable chart.cursor.Linex and LineY

I have followed the instruction as per documentation .

```js
/**
 * ---------------------------------------
 * This demo was created using amCharts 4.
 *
 * For more information visit:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/
 *
 * Documentation is available at:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/
 * ---------------------------------------
 */

/* Create chart instance */
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

/* Add data */
chart.data = [{
  "year": "1994",
  "cars": 1587,
  "motorcycles": 650,
  "bicycles": 121
}, {
  "year": "1995",
  "cars": 1567,
  "motorcycles": 683,
  "bicycles": 146
}, {
  "year": "1996",
  "cars": 1617,
  "motorcycles": 691,
  "bicycles": 138
}, {
  "year": "1997",
  "cars": 1630,
  "motorcycles": 642,
  "bicycles": 127
}, {
  "year": "1998",
  "cars": 1660,
  "motorcycles": 699,
  "bicycles": 105
}, {
  "year": "1999",
  "cars": 1683,
  "motorcycles": 721,
  "bicycles": 109
}, {
  "year": "2000",
  "cars": 1691,
  "motorcycles": 737,
  "bicycles": 112
}, {
  "year": "2001",
  "cars": 1298,
  "motorcycles": 680,
  "bicycles": 101
}, {
  "year": "2002",
  "cars": 1275,
  "motorcycles": 664,
  "bicycles": 97
}, {
  "year": "2003",
  "cars": 1246,
  "motorcycles": 648,
  "bicycles": 93
}, {
  "year": "2004",
  "cars": 1218,
  "motorcycles": 637,
  "bicycles": 101
}, {
  "year": "2005",
  "cars": 1213,
  "motorcycles": 633,
  "bicycles": 87
}, {
  "year": "2006",
  "cars": 1199,
  "motorcycles": 621,
  "bicycles": 79
}, {
  "year": "2007",
  "cars": 1110,
  "motorcycles": 210,
  "bicycles": 81
}, {
  "year": "2008",
  "cars": 1165,
  "motorcycles": 232,
  "bicycles": 75
}, {
  "year": "2009",
  "cars": 1145,
  "motorcycles": 219,
  "bicycles": 88
}, {
  "year": "2010",
  "cars": 1163,
  "motorcycles": 201,
  "bicycles": 82
}, {
  "year": "2011",
  "cars": 1180,
  "motorcycles": 285,
  "bicycles": 87
}, {
  "year": "2012",
  "cars": 1159,
  "motorcycles": 277,
  "bicycles": 71
}];

/* Create axes */
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "year";

/* Create value axis */
var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

/* Create series */
var series1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series1.dataFields.valueY = "cars";
series1.dataFields.categoryX = "year";
series1.name = "Cars";
series1.strokeWidth = 3;
series1.tensionX = 0.7;
series1.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
series1.tooltipText = "{categoryX}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";

var series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series2.dataFields.valueY = "motorcycles";
series2.dataFields.categoryX = "year";
series2.name = "Motorcycles";
series2.strokeWidth = 3;
series2.tensionX = 0.7;
series2.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
series2.tooltipText = "{categoryX}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";

var series3 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series3.dataFields.valueY = "bicycles";
series3.dataFields.categoryX = "year";
series3.name = "Bicycles";
series3.strokeWidth = 3;
series3.tensionX = 0.7;
series3.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
series3.tooltipText = "{categoryX}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";

/* Add legend */
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();

/* Create a cursor */
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.snapToSeries = [series1, series2, series3];
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

I have Cursor "snap" to actual data items of the series by setting its snapToSeries property to either a Series reference or an array of Series references.

```
chart.cursor.snapToSeries = [series1, series2, series3];
```

Now, the cursor will not follow mouse cursor but rather snap to the neares data point out of all the series set in snapToSeries.

the problem is that in this case the horizontal line chart.cursor.lineX just appear on the left side of the chart , i want to appear it on full chart right and left , when i remove

```
chart.cursor.snapToSeries = [series1, series2, series3];
```

then it appear full

I want to use

```
chart.cursor.snapToSeries = [series1, series2, series3];
```

but with axis lines (LineX and LineY) to appear on whole chart like in the image

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo3eH.png)